# WebRTC performance - very high cpu load

Tags: javascript, performance, html, html5-canvas, webrtc

Working on a motion detector [js library](https://github.com/alonisser/WebcamSwiper) built with [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) + canvas. 
When I run the app I immediately get very high cpu usage.
I optimized the loops etc, but the basic problem seems to be accessing the camera eg WebRTC.

**Is there a way to make WebRTC behave better?** Perhaps another configuration? Or is there something I'm missing? Could this be some js memory leak I'm handling wrong?
What am I doing wrong?

You can check another demo [here](http://swiper.4p-tech.co.il) with the same lib

and a different one using WebRTC and with same problem [here](http://enotionz.github.com/jscii/)

Comment: I've tested the demo at http://iambrandonn.github.com/WebcamSwiper and it doesn't use more than 20% CPU time. I think you should keep in mind that WebRTC is far from production ready - both the API and the underlying protocols are undergoing major changes still. Do you get the high CPU load in every browser or just on a specific one?

Comment: did you test the other one as well? also I can test only in chrome 22 because this is implented in other browsers yet..

Comment: getUserMedia is now available in Firefox Aurora/Nightly and Opera – would be good to test on these. (See www.simpl.info/gum for a demo that works on all three platforms.) The Ericsson Bowser mobile browser also implements WebRTC, including gUM. Also, just to be pedantic, note that'WebRTC' gets used to mean gUM, whereas WebRTC is really the whole realtime-communication-in-the-browser project, including RTCPeerConnection and DataChannel. Without all three APIs, there's Web, but no RTC! gUM is just the part that gets streaming data.

Answer (score 7):

The demo looks like it does motion detection by inspecting the video image's pixels.  It appears to render it to a canvas then retrieve the canvas image data.

This is slow because it's just a slow thing to do - there are lots of pixels, frames come through quickly, and it's a high CPU job.  It's made worse by the fact Javascript is not always very efficient at this kind of data-heavy processing.  So I don't think the slowness is inherent to WebRTC.  It's just heavy javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) for the computation?

There is a [demo using web workers for motion tracking](http://htmlfive.appspot.com/static/tracker1.html) (Firefox only). CPU usage does seem high in this demo but the worker's reported fps is way over the framerate of the video so there might be some benefit to try and limit the worker to 30fps.

Comment: why would using webworkers be faster? non blocking perhaps but faster? is the web worker  using a different thread?

Comment: Yes, they run in a separate thread from the UI thread. Taking it further you could start multiple workers and distribute the work in a MapReduce fashion to increase performance. For CPU usage though, YMMV.